# Golang's "internal error: duplicate loads" - how to resolve this error?

Tags: go

I am new in go. I have used external package in my project. I have tried to the below command for getting all imported packages,

go get -v all

It will throw duplicate loads error. What is the problem of this. How can I resolve this error ?

```
go get -v all
internal error: duplicate loads of unsafe
internal error: duplicate loads of runtime
internal error: duplicate loads of errors
internal error: duplicate loads of sync/atomic
internal error: duplicate loads of sync
internal error: duplicate loads of io
internal error: duplicate loads of unicode
internal error: duplicate loads of unicode/utf8
internal error: duplicate loads of bytes
internal error: duplicate loads of bufio
internal error: duplicate loads of math
internal error: duplicate loads of strconv
internal error: duplicate loads of reflect
internal error: duplicate loads of encoding/binary
internal error: duplicate loads of syscall
internal error: duplicate loads of time
internal error: duplicate loads of os
internal error: duplicate loads of fmt
internal error: duplicate loads of sort
internal error: duplicate loads of strings
internal error: duplicate loads of path/filepath
internal error: duplicate loads of path
```

Comment: what version of go you are using? 1.5beta? there are some issue in 1.5 related to this. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11913#issuecomment-127019561 In go 1.4 probablly it will work fine. as works on my.

You can try 
- go install -v all" instead
- go get ./...
- go get -u

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I am using go1.5.1 darwin/amd64 version. I have already visit the above issue. But, not able to get solutions.

Comment: You can try - 
go install -v all
go get ./... 
go get -u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `all` as argument to `go get`. That's not how it works.

"all" ist special and means "the whole standard library" and you don't need (and cannot) `go get` the standard library (as it is part of your Go installation).

Take a close look at the documentation of the go tool, e.g. by `go help` or `go help get`.  To get an external package foo/bar/baz use `go get foo/bar/baz`.

There is no (simple, newbie suitable) way to get all imported external packages. The most sensible way is to `go get the/external/package` and *then* use it in your code, not the other way around.